# Why is no request logged by IIS?

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am making Ajax `DELETE` request (from another server) to my `asp.net web api`. I can see that the `OPTIONS` request was logged in IIS and also captured by Wireshark. But just after that, `DELETE` is not captured. I have enabled `'All Verbs'` in Request Filtering and restarted IIS too. Is there any reason as to why this happens? In my client, I am always getting `403 Access Denied` as response on `DELETE` request, while `OPTIONS`, like I said, is `200 OK`.

Comment: have you enabled request tracing in your IIS website?

Comment: Yes, I can see other requests in the log.

Comment: Just a question - If Firewall is blocking any incoming request, then will it be logged by IIS or not?

Comment: I would say no, because the firewall sits in front of everything. try to open the respective port or turn off the firewall if it's a testing machine...

Comment: It is an AWS EC2 instance, so i guess even if I turn off Firewall, it shall be regulated by Security Groups. I will try that anyways.